# How do I echo out from bottom to top in PHP

Tags: php, html

I was trying to make a blog with PHP. I used this code for submitting posts into the database.

```
<form method="POST" action="makePost.php">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="title">
    <textarea name="post"></textarea>
    <button name="submit">POST</button>
</form>
```

makePost.php:

```
<?php
    include_once "database.php";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $postMessage = $_POST['post'];
        $execution = "INSERT INTO blog(id, title, post) VALUES ('', '$title', '$postMessage');";
        mysqli_query($database, $execution);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

and then this is how I tried to echo out posts on the main page.

```
<?php
    include_once "database.php";
    $execution = "SELECT * FROM blog";
    $entires = mysqli_query($database, $execution);
    while ($row = $entires->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
        echo "<div>".$row['post']."</div>";
    }
?>
```

The problem is that this code spits out the first posts to the top, while newer posts go to the bottom, but I need to make new posts go above older ones since that`s how blogs are supposed to work.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY yourField DESC`

Comment: I think that is a problem with your MySQL query. Try `ORDER BY` with your MySQL query.

Comment: use ORDER BY :)
one tip more, never pass data from $_POST directly to the query - read more about SQL Injection

Comment: Just as a hint for the next time: check where the problem really occurs. In your case, you should have had a look at the result for that executed SQL query first to see that your problem is in no way related to HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the problem is with your `SQL` query. If you run this query `SELECT * FROM blog` in your database you will get records in Ascending Order (ASC) and you can see the same order follows by the PHP when `echo` the results. So the easiest and best way to achieve what you need is using MySQL `ORDER BY` clause.

**Ascending Order (ASC)** - In your case, it is Oldest Records to the Lastest Records

**Descending Order (DESC)** - In your case, it is Latest Records to the Oldest Records

So your MySQL query should be like the following,

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY your_field DESC
```

`your_field` is up to you to choose. Because I don't know the table structure. It should be the `id` field or the `timestamp` field or any other field that we can order the records by ASC or DESC.

So finally your code should be,

```
<?php
    include_once "database.php";
    $execution = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY your_field DESC";
    $entires = mysqli_query($database, $execution);
    while ($row = $entires->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
        echo "<div>".$row['post']."</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your query which has no Order by clause.

To get the desired output, Just change your code like:

```
<?php
    include_once "database.php";
    $execution = "SELECT * FROM blog Order by date DESC";
    $entires = mysqli_query($database, $execution);
    while ($row = $entires->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
        echo "<div>".$row['post']."</div>";
    }
?>
```

DESC is used to get data in descending format with Order by clause

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no date field in the table, you can use the id to sort posts

```
$execution = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Note that your code is vulnerable to sql injection you should use binding when you save your post

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is ordering the posts during the query at the database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC
```

Ordering by ID DESC, the query get all the posts, starting with the one with higher ID and the last with the lower ID.

I don't actually know how oyur table `blog` is. The best pratice would order by a date, but if you gave AUTOINCREMENT to your ID, it should follow the match "the higher, the newer".

ps in MakePost.php, when you insert new record into db, tou don't need to specify the id if you don't pass it through the values:

```sql
INSERT INTO blog (title, post) VALUES ('title off the post', 'text');
```

Mysql will give automatically an incremental ID at every insert (if you specify the AUTOINCREMENT to ID attribute )